# Вопрос по Autocomplete textbox с#

Tags: c#, autocomplete

Есть таблица "kontr" с полями id,name,type. На форме есть textbox на нем стоит автозаполнение из таблицы "kontr". При вводе начальных букв выводится подсказка. Как сделать так чтобы при выборе подсказки записывался id этой строки в заранее объявленную переменную?

```
таблица kontr
1, Вася, 1
2, Петя, 0
3. Александр, 1
```

код автозаполнения

```
    txt_kontrIn.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    txt_kontrIn.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    AutoCompleteStringCollection kontrInCol = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    getKontrName(kontrInCol, 1); 
    txt_kontrIn.AutoCompleteCustomSource = kontrInCol;
```

код getcontrName

```
    int pid;
    private void getKontrName(AutoCompleteStringCollection col, int type)
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(core.conString);
        con.Open();

        string q = @"select name from kontr where type = "+type.ToString()+"";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(q, con);
        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if(dr.HasRows == true)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {

                col.Add(dr["name"].ToString());
                //Нужно чтобы еще записался id выбранной записи в переменную pid
            }
            dr.Close();
            con.Close();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Вы читаете базу данных в UI-потоке? Ох.

Comment: Пока да, потом будет вынесено за пределы формы.

Comment: Вопрос остается открытым, так как сделать так, чтобы записывался id выбранной записи в переменную?

Comment: @Artneo, у Вас все получилось? Нужны еще пояснения?

Comment: к сожалению  нет, думаю теперь в сторону combobox, т.к. у него есть нужные атрибуты "ValueMember" и "DisplayMember".

Comment: @Artneo, На мой взгляд, СomboBox это лучший вариант, если нужно делать выбор на форме. Вы можете его инициализировать в цикле из предложенного Вам варианта решения  comboBox.Items.Add(new NameId (dr["name"].ToString(),(int)dr["id"])

Comment: @Artneo, там настоятельно рекомендуют перенести обсуждение, которое ниже в ответе из ответа в чат, что я и сделал.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51785/discussion-between-artneo-and--).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может, я что-то не понимаю, но что мешает дополнить запрос еще одним полем

`string q = @"select name, id from kontr where type = "+type.ToString()+"";`

и дальше значение `dr["id"]` после преобразования присвоить переменной Pid?

По результатам Ваших вопросов в комментариях, сделаю следующее дополнение, которое корректирую по уже по Вашей обратной связи :). У Вас есть два варианта

1. вместо `AutoCompleteStringCollection` использовать коллекцию https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21400452/autocompletestringcollection-with-tags-for-each-string
2. использовать не ТехтBox, а ComboBox, добавляя NameId непосредственно comboBox.Items, где NameId Ваш вспомогательный класс

   ```
   class NameId 
   {
   int id;
   public int Pid   { get { return id; }  }

   string name;
   public NameId(string _name, int _id)
   {
       name = _name;
       id = _id;
   }
   public override string ToString()
   {
       return name;
   }
   }
   ```

Соответственно читать нужно так

```
    if(dr.HasRows == true)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            comboBox.Items.Add(new NameId (dr["name"].ToString(),(int)dr["id"]);
        }
        dr.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Незабудьте про try { } catch() - это сэкономит Вам много времени.

Естественно, что это только иллюстрированная схема возможного решения Вашей проблемы, которую Вам придется "допилить напильником" уже самому :)

Comment: if(dr.HasRows == true)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {

                col.Add(dr["name"].ToString());
                pid = (int)dr["id"]; // таким образом?
            }
            dr.Close();
            con.Close();

        }

Comment: Если Вы получаете в запросе единственную запись, то да. Если записей много,  то в коллекцию Вы должны добавлять не "string", а свой класс, в котором предусмотрено хранение имени и идентификатора.

Comment: а можно пример привести? а то не совсем понятно.

Comment: Соответственно, в Вашем классе будет нужно переопределить наследуемый метод ToString

Comment: Выдает ошибку "не удается преобразовать в test.one.nameId в string"

Comment: Блина-блина - был не внимателен - у Вас string Collection, а не object. Есть два пути: первый использовать эту коллекцию http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21400452/autocompletestringcollection-with-tags-for-each-string. Второй - для навигации использовать не ТехтBox, а ListBox, добавляя NameId непосредственно в listBox.Items

Comment: а если использовать combobox вместо textbox?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51781/discussion-between---and-artneo).